# How to create a fade-out-in effect for specific elements when the page is done loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, fade

I'm trying to create a fade-out-in effect for a specific div element when the page is done loading. Unfortunately I didn't get it to work.

It works with body but not for a div element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.transition').removeClass('fade-out');
});
$(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('fade-out');
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

body.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
}

.transition {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

.transition fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.body.className += ' fade-out';
</script>



<div class="transition">
  <script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('.transition') += 'fade-out';
  </script>
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

In conclusion: I don't want to have the whole body element to fade-out as soon as the page loads but rather for the class element "transition".

Comment: `.transition fade-out`. `fade-out` is a class. It should be `.transition .fade-out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('.transition')` return collection of HTMLElements, instead of single element.

Use `document.querySelector` to select single element.

```js
$('.transition').removeClass('fade-out');
```

```css
.transition {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

.transition.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transition fade-out">
  <p>TEST</p>
</div>
```

-- Edit --

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.transition, .canvas')
  .forEach((ele) => {
    console.log('Before: ', ele);
    ele.classList.remove('fadeout');
    console.log('After: ', ele);
  });
```

```html
<div class="transition fadeout">Transition</div>
<div class="canvas fadeout">Canvas</div>
```

Comment: nice! working but got another problem with the element canvas (webgl). $(function() {
  $('.transition, .canvas').removeClass('fade-out');
});

document.querySelector('.transition, .canvas').className += ' fade-out';

still doesn't work?

Comment: As you are using jquery you can use `$('.transition, .canvas').removeClass( "fade-out" );`. `querySelector` accepts only one selector.

Comment: ok, i've also tried `document.querySelectorAll('.transition, .canvas');`
 but still diesn't work

Comment: @jkr137 - You are almost close. The `querySelectorAll` return nodeList array. Apply loop to get single element. Also, `removeClass` work on jQuery objects and it is not javascript method. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("transition"); 
element.classList.add("fade-out");
```